# Which managed policy does kms:ListAliases belong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am getting this notice when trying to create an Aurora instance:

```
Error loading KMS Keys
User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/xxx is not authorized to perform: kms:ListAliases on resource: *
```

Does any one know which managed policy does `kms:ListAliases` belong? Can't seem to find it in the pre-made manage policies. Or maybe it doesn't exist in the managed policies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser` includes Action `kms:List*` on all Resources.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I actually checked that but missed the wildcard `*`. Nice catch.